# RAID 10 can not be started

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

I have a RAID 10 array managed with `mdadm` which has failed . The symptom was that X has crashed and I was unable to logon from the terminal. I have restarted the computer and `/dev/md1` did not start.

I've gathered the following information - some incomplete as I've manually copied it to another computer:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat

....

md1 :   inactive sdb3[1](S) sdd1[3](S) sdc2[2](S) sda1[0](S)
        1250273760 blocks super 1.0
```

Mounting has failed

```
$ mount /dev/md1    
EXT4-fs (md1): unable to read superblock
```

Scanning did find the metadata

```
$ mdadm --examine --scan
...
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.0 UUID=2c... name=linux:1
```

Running has failed due to lack of operational mirrors

```
$ mdadm --run /dev/md1
md/raid0:md1: not enough operational mirrors.
md: pers->run() failed...
mdadm:failed to run array /dev/md1: Input/output error
```

After the run attempt only two disks were still in the array

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
....
md1  : inactive sdd1[3] sdc2[2]
       62513638 blocks super 1.0
```

Trying to re-add one disk has failed

```
$ mdadm /dev/md1 --add /dev/sda1
mdadm: /dev/sda1 reports being an active member for /dev/md1, but --re-add fails
mdadm: not performing --add as that would convert /dev/sda1 in to a spare
mdadm: To make this a spare, use "mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda1" first
```

I've recorded some metadata in order to try recreating the array

```
$ mdadm --examine /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sda1 | grep -E 'dev|Update|Role|State|Chunk Size'
/dev/sdb3:
  State: active
  Update time:  Mon May 14 21:51:41 2012
  Chunk Size: 256K
  Device Role: Active device 1
  Array State : AAAA
/dev/sdd1:
  State: active
  Update time:  Mon May 14 22:11:11 2012
  Chunk Size: 256K
  Device Role: Active device 3
  Array State : ..AA
/dev/sdc2:
  State: active
  Update time:  Mon May 14 22:11:11 2012
  Chunk Size: 256K
  Device Role: Active device 2
  Array State : ..AA
/dev/sda1:
  State: active
  Update time:  Mon May 14 21:51:41 2012
  Chunk Size: 256K
  Device Role: Active device 0
  Array State : AAAA
```

I've tried manually recreating the array based on the previously recorded information

```
$ mdadm --create --metadata=1.0 --assume-clean --level=10 --raid-devices=4 --chunk=256K /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdd1
mdadm: /dev/sda1 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
mdadm: /dev/sda1 appears to be part of a raid array
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 appears to be part of a raid array
mdadmin: /dev/sdc2 appears to be part of a raid aray
mdadmin: /dev/sdd1 appears to be part of a raid aray
```

Mounting fails again which probably means that the raid is not properly created

$ mount /dev/md1 /mnt

```
EXT4-fs (md1): ext4_check_descriptors: Checksum forgroup 0 failed (54076!=0)
EXT4-fs (md1): group descriptors corrupted!
```

Running a fsck yielded too many errors to take into account seriously so I did not let it run.

I've tried recreating the array with 'missing' devices and just a two disks, but no combination was successful. I'm not sure if I tried them all, but I did try many.

---

Some details:

- `mdadm` is version 2.3.2, running on OpenSUSE 12.1, kernel 3.1.10, x86_64
- all hard disks have completed `smartctl -t short` without any errors

How can I rebuild the RAID array without losing the information *or* just extract the information and copy it somewhere else? I'm also curious to know if there is anything that I did wrong above when trying to recreate the array.

Comment: Are there any disk IO errors showing up in `dmesg`?

Comment: @psusi - I don't see any disk errors. However, I suspect that there is an issue with the partition tables. `sda` and `sdb` are shown as having intel partition tables, while `sdc` and `sdd` are shown as having EPT partition tables.

I did not partition manually - I used YAST - and I see no reason to mix partition table types.

Comment: You mean msdos and gpt partition tables?  That shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @psusi I understand that it should not be a problem but that smells wrong - I don't know why YAST would do it this way. Anyway, using `testdisk` and some help I've managed to repair the partition table on /dev/sdd and after a e2fsck -y I've managed to mount the drive. Now the array is rebuilding. If this is succesful I will post an answer with the solution.

Comment: [I realize this is old, but]... When your raid array has failed, and you are tempted to run `mdadm --create`, then **STOP**. It is almost never the right answer. The right answer depends on what exactly caused the failure, the value of the data, and the budget available for recovery.

Comment: BTW: your `--examine` output shows that you suffered a double-disk failure, and then possibly another. Hard to tell for sure without the fields you omitted. Most likely `mdadm --stop /dev/md1; mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdd1` would have worked, with less data corruption. Or maybe even just `--run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help, I managed to rebuild a degraded array in the following manner:

1. Use the [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) utility and notice that the `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd` disks were marked with a GPT partition table
2. Fix the partition table on `/dev/sdd` to have the partition type listed as `fd` instead of `83`
3. Create a RAID array with only `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdd1`
4. Run `e2fsck -y /dev/md1` ( expect lots of fixes )

A useful hint when rebuilding raid arrays is to peek at the first 100 MB of the raw device to see if it looks like a valid ext2 which should be passed to e2fsck:

```
dd if=/dev/md1 of=/tmp/md1.img bs=1k count=1024
strings md1.img | lesss
```